# Loading data into Amazon Redshift: Ignore last n rows

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Is there an option to load a CSV into Redshift while skipping over a footer?

Just like we use `ignoreheader` when we want to ignore initial rows. If we want to ignore last rows is there any way?

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no parameter to tell the `COPY` command to ignore rows at the end of a file.

However, you could load the file with an error by specifying a [`MAXERROR`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-load.html#copy-maxerror) of `1`, which will allow the file to load with one bad row (or more, if required).